# iphone sdk: UIScrollView as Image

Tags: iphone

I want to save the content of an UiScrollView as an Image. It seems that it is not as easy as the UIImageRepresentation that can be used for Views or ImageViews, anyone an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a method implemented in a category:

```
+ (UIImage *)screenshot:(UIView *)view {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CALayer *layer = view.layer;
    [layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

but, in your case, I suppose it will not suit well if your need is to get the whole content (also the part not visible in that moment). You could change the zoom value and then take the screenshot if it's a good enough solution.